# Detect several elements from position using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver

I have such problem:

there is a link with position 6,83 which is overlapped by empty *div* which overlaps *whole* page.

this link is not clickable because of it's overlapped. but! when I'm trying to execute `document.elementFromPoint(6,83)` it returns me not my div, but link :( How can I detect this div overlapping link?

I need this in Java + WebDriver but JS can be a solution also.

Thank you.

UPD: (I have not enough rating):
I have found the solution! It's strange, but if `document.elementFromPoint` called for top-left coordinates of element it will return same element even it is overlapped. That's why we can check overlapping in CENTER of our element.

As I asked about WebDriver, here is the solution:

`public static boolean isElementClickable(WebElement element) {
        return  element.isDisplayed()
                && element.isEnabled()
                && element.equals(getJSExecutor(getDriverFromContext(element))
                .executeScript("return document.elementFromPoint" +
                "(" + Integer.toString(((Locatable)element).getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView().getX() + (element.getSize().getWidth() / 2)) +
                ", " + Integer.toString(((Locatable)element).getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView().getY() + (element.getSize().getHeight() / 2)) + ")"));
    }`

I hope this will help anybody with same problem or with element is clickable problem in WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I asked about WebDriver, here is the solution:

```
public static boolean isElementClickable(WebElement element) { 
    return element.isDisplayed() && element.isEnabled() && 
    element.equals(getJSExecutor(getDriverFromContext(element)) .executeScript(
        "return document.elementFromPoint" + "(" + 
        Integer.toString(((Locatable)element).getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView().getX() + 
        (element.getSize().getWidth() / 2)) + ", " + 
        Integer.toString(((Locatable)element).getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView().getY() + 
        (element.getSize().getHeight() / 2)) + ")")); 
}
```

I hope this will help anybody with same problem or with element is clickable problem in WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [elementFromPoint](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t20) or [getBoundingClientRect](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/) method.
Please see both of these method link for more details.

**elementFromPoint:** This method is a godsend for drag and drop scripts. When the user drops the dragged element, figure out what element is located at the drop point and go on from there. No more complicated calculations necessary.

**getBoundingClientRect:** This is a method, first introduced by Internet Explorer 5 (and now included in Firefox 3), which provides the top, right, bottom, and left offset coordinates of an element. After PPK mentioned this method in a recent post of his, poo-poo-ing its applicability, I thought I’d take some time to show how useful it can be. What makes this method so especially handy is that the alternative means of computing an element’s offset position is so horribly slow and buggy that it borders on the comical.

Comment: it seems to be large and slow solution. I've made some experiments with my page, and such behaviour I see only with links. for example, I have also input text field with coordinates nearby 250/170 which is overlapped the same div, and `document.elementFromPoint(250,170)` returns exactly this input. It's rather strange behaviour. z-index of my div is 199, link 3, input also 3.